# Java: Close Specific JFrame Window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I hope everyone is doing well.

I've built a hangman game with a swing gui and everything works well enough, HOWEVER I am trying to make a popup show up by constructing a new JFrame object when the user wins or loses with a "you lose" message or what have you. No problem, but I want a specific window to close when activating the button listener on the popup, or when the 'x' is clicked. Assume my program has 3 windows up, and I only want to close 2 of them with one click.

I tried stuff in the area of

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

But that specific one closes all the windows. If you want to see more specific sample code, I would happy to provide it, but it didn't seem necessary for this question.

Either way, I can't figure out how to do this. Is this possible using Swing?

Thank you so much in advance. You guys are always so helpful.

Comment: Use a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame` - possible using `JOptionPane` which will help simplify the matter.  If you want to close "other" windows, then you will need a reference to them before you can call their `dispose` methods

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Thanks so much for the very clear answer. If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it as "best answer".

Comment: @AndrewThompson- Thank you for your reply, but this was answered within 5 minutes of it being asked by Mad Programmer. It is impossible to give a code example when my question is, "is this possible". I really appreciate the reference to the "good/bad practice" information. It will help greatly.